# Best way to find code and data sections in COFF object files?

Tags: c++, c, coff

I want to find the **CODE** and **Initialized DATA** sections in **COFF Object files**.

The sections that I want to find are called **.text$mn** and **.data** in output generated from two versions of Microsoft "c" compilers.

I have no idea how consistent this is across different compiler vendors, compiler versions from one vendor or different compiled languages from the same compiler vendor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Table 7. Section Header Flags**
STYP_TEXT 00000020h Section contains executable code
STYP_DATA 00000040h Section contains initialized data
[Common Object File Format](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/spraao8/spraao8.pdf?ts=1599623019662&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)
Does narrow down the options, yet derived two different data sections.

On the Microsoft platform searching for these section names in the Symbol_Table  seems to work reliably: **.text$mn** and **.data**. I may have to adapt this for the gcc compiler.